# How to programmatically keep an active call on hold?

Tags: android

How can I programmatically keep an active call on hold from the OFFHOOK state on Android?

Comment: Seems that, No one knows the solution for this!!!

Comment: do you found any solution for this

Comment: No not yet.... left it as it is.....

Comment: Ok thanks for replay